# Topology riddle - dense infinite subset

Tags: general-topology, puzzle

Made up this question while thinking about something in topology and thought I'd post it here for fun, to see how you guys might solve it:

Give an example or disprove the existence of an infinite, topological Hausdorff space $(X,\tau)$ in which every infinite subset is dense.

Comment: Ok, so either my reasoning is off, or this isn't a duplicate - A $T_1$ space may not be Hausdorff. Under my assumptions we'd get the topology must be the co-finite topology. But not the other way around. My question isn't answered by the one you posted, I think.

Comment: If there exists an infinite Hausdorff space $(X,\tau)$ in which every infinite subset is dense, then this space is also $T_1$. So according to the dup question, $\tau$ is cofinite, contradicting Hausdorff. Hence no such space exists. - While this is a quick consequence of the linked question, it may be exaggerated to call it an (exact) duplicate. Nevertheless, "This question already has an answer (there)"